# Despite using the 'no markers' option, I still get plotmarks in my legend. Why?

Tags: pgfplots, legend

Nice to finally post a question myself after finding solutions to my problems on numerous occasions within these forums. I hope someone can be of help (and that this hasn't been asked already).

The problem is as follows: I'm using pgfplots for the plots within my document. I used the procedure described in section 4.8.7 (Legends outside of an axis) within the pgfplots manual in order to create one legend for several horizontally aligned plots. In general this works fine. My issue is, that the marker style differs between the plot and the legend. I am using the `no markers` option with `\addplot`. The legend shows the correct line style but also markers. Is it possible to remove the markers? Did I place the `ref{}` command to reference the legend in the wrong place? I couldn't find any solution by browsing google or within the manual, hence my question.

The code looks as follows (I can post a minimum working example if necessary):

```
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}
[
legend columns=-1,
legend entries={$Pe_{ax} = 1$;,$Pe_{ax} = 10$;,$Pe_{ax} = 100$;,$Pe_{ax} = 1000$},
legend to name=named3,
width=6cm, height=6cm, 
xmin={0},
xmax={2},
ymin={0},
ymax={2},
xtick={0,1,2},
ytick={0,2},
xlabel= {$\Theta [-]$},
ylabel={$E(\Theta) [-]$},
label style={font=\footnotesize},
tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
legend style={draw=none}
]
\addplot+[no markers,smooth, color=black, dashed] coordinates {(1,0) (1,2)};
\addplot+[no markers,smooth, color=black, dotted] table[x=X,y=Y1] {Tabellen/Butt_1999_Bo1.txt};
\addplot+[no markers,smooth, color=black, dashdotdotted] table[x=X,y=Y1] {Tabellen/Butt_1999_Bo10.txt};
\addplot+[no markers,smooth, color=black, dashdotted] table[x=X,y=Y1] {Tabellen/Butt_1999_Bo100.txt};
\addplot+[no markers,smooth, color=black, solid] table[x=X,y=Y1] {Tabellen/Butt_1999_Bo1000.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{0cm}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}
[
width=6cm, height=6cm, 
xmin={0},
xmax={2},
ymin={0},
ymax={1},
xtick={0,1,2},
ytick={0,1},
xlabel= {$\Theta [-]$},
ylabel={$F(\Theta) [-]$},
label style={font=\footnotesize},
tick label style={font=\footnotesize}
]
\addplot+[no markers,smooth, color=black, dashed] coordinates {(1,0) (1,1)};
\addplot+[no markers,smooth, color=black, dotted] table[x=X,y=Y2] {Tabellen/Butt_1999_Bo1.txt};
\addplot+[no markers,smooth, color=black, dashdotdotted] table[x=X,y=Y2] {Tabellen/Butt_1999_Bo10.txt};
\addplot+[no markers,smooth, color=black, dashdotted] table[x=X,y=Y2] {Tabellen/Butt_1999_Bo100.txt};
\addplot+[no markers,smooth, color=black, solid] table[x=X,y=Y2] {Tabellen/Butt_1999_Bo1000.txt};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\ref{named3}
\caption{Text.}
\end{figure}
```

Hope this helps! Thanks in advance for any ideas, thoughts and the like!

Edit: as requested here is a minimum working example of the problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\pgfplotsset{domain=-1:1}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}
[
legend columns=-1,
legend entries={$x^2$;,$x^3$;,$x^4$;,$x^5$},
legend to name=named,
width=6cm, height=6cm, 
xlabel= {$x$},
ylabel={$f(x)$},
legend style={draw=none}
]
\addplot+[no markers,smooth, color=black, dashed]{x^2};
\addplot+[no markers,smooth, color=black, solid] {x^3};
\addplot+[no markers,smooth, color=black, dashdotdotted] {x^4};
\addplot+[no markers,smooth, color=black, dashdotted] {x^5};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{0cm}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}
[
width=6cm, height=6cm, 
xlabel= {$x$},
ylabel={$f'(x)$},
]
\addplot+[no markers,smooth, color=black, dashed]{2*x};
\addplot+[no markers,smooth, color=black, solid] {3*x^2};
\addplot+[no markers,smooth, color=black, dashdotdotted] {4*x^3};
\addplot+[no markers,smooth, color=black, dashdotted] {5*x^4};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\ref{named}
\caption{Minimum working example.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As you're not using any markers, you could just add `no markers` as an option to the `axis`, this also removes them from the legend. Would that be good enough? I cannot explain why the problem occurs.

Comment: Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Thanks a lot! Somehow my initial greeting wasn't posted so...good morning everybody!

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I tried to do so (as explained below) but that doesn't solve the problem. The legend disappears completely except for the legend text and is put in a strange position.

Comment: If I take your MWE, and add `no markers` to the first `axis`, I get the desired output. Doesn't that work for you? Same result if I remove that option from all `\addplot+` and add it to the second `axis` as well.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. When I remove `no markers` from all `\addplot+[...]` and add it to `begin{axis}[...]` I get the following result:
[http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/23/9jxk.jpg/]

Comment: I get http://i.imgur.com/frgM8zY.png You don't have any old versions of `pgfplots` lying around do you? Add `\listfiles` to the preamble to get  list of packages with versions in the log file.

Comment: I uploaded the .log-file here:
http://www.sendspace.com/file/m6y9cc
I don't know how to comprehend it myself though.  I am not aware of any previous installation of pgfplots. Actually, I had to install it specifically in order to use it. Maybe something went wrong during the installation process?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note: I'm assuming you're using `pgfplots` v1.8.

You're passing the `no markers` option to `\addplot+`, but `no markers` is an option available for the `axis` environment, not for `\addplot` commands. That's likely the problem.

`no markers` (assuming it is passed to `axis`) does exactly what you want, i.e. disable all plotmarks on all the graphs within that `axis` environment; [Torbjørn T.'s comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129947/customize-marker-and-line-style-for-a-legend-outside-of-an-axis-pgfplots-with-t#comment292858_129947) is sound.

```
\begin{axis}[no markers,...]
\addplot+[...] ... ;
...
\end{axis}
```

To disable markers on a given `\addplot` (or `\addplot+`), you can pass the `mark=none` option to that command.

```
\begin{axis}[...]
\addplot+[mark=none,...] ... ;
...
\end{axis}
```

However, neither

```
\addplot+[no markers,...] ... ;
```

nor

```
\begin{axis}[mark=none,...]
...
\end{axis}
```

will produce the desired result, as your MWE demonstrates.

**References**:

- Section 4.6.1 of the [`pgfplots` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf)
- See also [this answer by Jake](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25023/21891).

### Addendum

(following a conversation with percusse)

Revision 1.8 (2013/03/17) of the [`pgfplots` manual](http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/CTAN/tex/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf) also makes one reference (in the last code sample of section 5.8.1) to a `no marks` option for `\addplot`, but this option is documented nowhere in the manual. Perhaps the maintainer can shed some light on the matter if he finds this post, but for now, it's safe to assume that the `no marks` option has become obsolete and that it's probably best not to use it from now on.

---

**Edit**: the following code produces the desired output for me.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\pgfplotsset{domain=-1:1}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}
[
legend columns=-1,
legend entries={$x^2$;,$x^3$;,$x^4$;,$x^5$},
legend to name=named,
width=6cm, height=6cm, 
xlabel= {$x$},
ylabel={$f(x)$},
legend style={draw=none},
no markers,
]
\addplot+[smooth, color=black, dashed]{x^2};
\addplot+[smooth, color=black, solid] {x^3};
\addplot+[smooth, color=black, dashdotdotted] {x^4};
\addplot+[smooth, color=black, dashdotted] {x^5};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{0cm}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\begin{axis}
[
width=6cm, height=6cm, 
xlabel= {$x$},
ylabel={$f'(x)$},
no markers,
]
\addplot+[smooth, color=black, dashed]{2*x};
\addplot+[smooth, color=black, solid] {3*x^2};
\addplot+[smooth, color=black, dashdotdotted] {4*x^3};
\addplot+[smooth, color=black, dashdotted] {5*x^4};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\ref{named}
\caption{Minimum working example.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the rapid answers! Indeed, I'm using `pgfplots` v1.8.

So far, using `no markers` with the `axis` environment worked fine with me. Usually the legend entries are in accordance with the plot. I tried to remove the `no markers` option from the line featuring `\addplot+[...]` and adding it instead to `\begin{axis}[...]`. The result looks even stranger. The legend entries are put in a rather random position next to the plot without markers or line styles, just plain text.

Comment: @Tovja See my edit. Do you obtain the same output?

Comment: Yes, I do. Works like a charm. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Now I see my mistake. I added the option `no markers` to the `axis` environment to a new set of `[...]` instead of simply adding it to the existing one. No wonder it did not work.

Comment: @Tovja Glad we figured out what went wrong :)

Comment: Regarding the `no marks` option: This is a TikZ style (have a look at [section 22.7 in the pgfmanual on page 333 (v3.0.1a)](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#page=333)). I already reported that a while ago [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/131/).