# I still get plot points in my plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{TikZ}
\usepackage{PGF}
\usepackage{pgfplots}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[x post scale=2, hide axis,width=2cm,height=2cm, mark=none ,black] 
\addplot+[domain=-3/2:3/2]({cos(deg(x))}, {x});
\end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture}




\end{document}
```

regardless of my using the mark=none command I still get plot points when I compile

Comment: Is there a reason as to why `\addplot` has a `+`  before the `[`? I removed it and the plot points were gone leaving a black line.

Comment: I guess that's just a habit I picked up at some point, weird because all the other commands in the square brackets worked anyway, but thanks

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25023/

Comment: One last thing (sorry for comment flood): package file names are, at least on Linux, case sensitive, so it should be `\usepackage{tikz}` and `\usepackage{pgf}`. Except that none of them are actually needed here, because `pgfplots` loads `tikz`, and `tikz` loads `pgf`, so they're loaded anyway.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

removing the `+` between `\addplot` and `[` fixed it

Comment: To explain *why* that worked: The `+` before the `[..]` means that the options in the brackets are *appended to* the default options (from the `cycle list` that is used). Without the `+`, the options you specify *replace* the default options, leaving you with a black line, and whatever other styling you specify. So it's not that removing the `+` makes the `mark=none,black` work. It's that by removing it and having a pair of brackets with some options, you've removed all colour and mark settings that the `\addplot` would otherwise use.

Comment: As mentioned in the link I posted in a comment to your question, you can use `\begin{axis}[no markers,...]` to remove markers from all plots, or `\addplot +[mark=none,...]` to remove markers from a specific plot. (`...` stand for any other options you might use).

Answer (score 1):

Placing `mark=none` parameter inside `\addplot` brackets

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[x post scale=5, hide axis,width=2cm,height=2cm, black] 
\addplot+[mark=none,domain=-3/2:3/2]({cos(deg(x))}, {x});
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Note**

It is not necessary to call both `pgf` and `tikz` (in lowercases) packages. `pgfplots` contains them both.